# Second order total differential for three variables

Tags: mathematical-economics

As the title says, how would you find a second order total differential for a three variable function. For instance:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For a function $f$ of $2$ variables $x,y$ its first order differential is

$df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} dy$

Note this can be seen as a linear operator $d$ applied to the function $f$

$d(f) =(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} dy) f$

Here the operator $d$ is

$d = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} dy$

$d^2 = (\frac{\partial}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} dy)^2$

$ d^2 = (\frac{\partial}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} dy)(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} dy)$

$ d^2 = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} dx^2 + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} dy^2 + 2 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y} dx dy$

Therefore, the second order differential of $f$ is:

$d^2 f = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} dx^2 + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} dy^2 + 2 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} dx dy$

Now for $3$ variables $x,y,z$

$df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} dy + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} dz$

Note this can be seen as a linear operator $d$ applied to the function $f$

$d(f) =(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} dy + \frac{\partial}{\partial z} dz) f$

Here the operator $d$ is

$d = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} dy + \frac{\partial}{\partial z} dz$

$d^2 = (\frac{\partial}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} dy + \frac{\partial}{\partial z} dz)^2$

$ d^2 = (\frac{\partial}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} dy  + \frac{\partial}{\partial z} dz)^2)(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} dy  + \frac{\partial}{\partial z} dz)^2)$

$ d^2 = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} dx^2 + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} dy^2 + \frac{\partial f^2}{\partial z^2} dz^2 + 2 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y} dx dy + 2 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial z} dx dz + 2 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y \partial z} dy dz$

Therefore, the second order differential of $f$ is:

$d^2 f = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} dx^2 + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} dy^2 + \frac{\partial f^2}{\partial z^2} dz^2 + 2 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} dx dy + 2 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial z} dx dz + 2 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial z} dy dz$

Similarly, for $n$ variables $x_1,\dots,x_n$ it’s

$d^2 f = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial {x_i}^2} d{x_i}^2 + 2 \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \sum_{j = 1, j > i}^{n} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} dx_i dx_j$

Comment: Thanks, but I also saw a formula for the second order total differential which only multiplied by 2 on one of the last three terms.